# keycloack authentication issue after webpack in electron browser

Tags: reactjs, webpack, keycloak

Im newbie in web development. I have implemented a keycloack based login mechanism on a electron browser using react and node js.

```
package.json => let initOptions = {
  url: 'my-url',
  realm: 'my-realm',
  clientId: 'my-client-id',
  grant_type: 'authorization_code',
  KeycloakResponseType: 'code',
  'sameSite': 'none',
  'secure': true,
  'ssl-required': 'external',
  'public-client': true,
  'confidential-port': 0,
  enableDebug: true, // Enable debug mode
  logLevel: 'debug'
  }
```

my-auth.js

```
 const initKeyCloack = () =>
  {
    kc.init({
      KeycloakResponseType: 'code',
      pkceMethod: 'S256',
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:10000',
      enableLogging: true
    }).then((auth) => {
      if (!auth) {
        console.log('not authenticated')
      } else {
        console.info("Authenticated");    
        kc.onTokenExpired = () => {
        console.log('token expired')
        }
      }
    }, () => {
      console.error("Authenticated Failed");
    });

  }
```

The code works, when "npm run start". But when the "npm build" is triggered and webpack files are generated and copied to a webserver path it doesnt work (login is successful and and but comes to not authenticated section, so i cant see the jwt token). Here electron is used as renderer.

Following didnt work, i would need new hints.

1. double check the redirect_uri => no problem here.
2. enabled logging. But no clues are printed.
3. tried to debug with keycloack in debugger. but im lost in the code.
4. removed silent sso check => didnt help
5. diabled all web preferences => didnt help.

Any new hints will be greatly appreaciated. Thanks.